# FRM-13008: Cannot find JavaBean with name 'oracle.forms.fd.Sound.'

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, javabeans, oracleforms

When I open the project and then open a canvas I get error: FRM-13008: Cannot find JavaBean with name 'oracle.forms.fd.Sound.'

I could'nt find "Sound" class under Program -> Import Java Classes.. What can I do?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h34H.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to Registry Editor, find FORMS_BUILDER_CLASSPATH
2. Add your "sound.jar" directory to value of it.

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies of the jar must be added in the FORMS_BUILDER_CLASSPATH too!